# Where is Solr core schema.xml?

Tags: solr

I have started Solr and created a core using the following commands. I would like to modify the schema.xml file but cannot find it anywhere. Do the following commands create a schema.xml file?

`bin\solr.cmd start`
`bin\solr.cmd create -c test`

Comment: it would be at location if you are using windows....C:\solr-7.6.0\solr-7.6.0\server\solr\configsets\_default\conf..

Comment: you are asking very basic questions...please read the solr documentation for more..https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/

Comment: I see `managed-schema`, isn't it wrong to touch this file? Shouldn't there be a dedicated schema.xml for this core under `C:\solr-8.1.1\server\solr\test`?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti "<!-- Solr managed schema - automatically generated - DO NOT EDIT -->"

Comment: then create your own configset...use the same configset for your core...and you can rename that managed schema to schema.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the managed schema (which you are by default when creating a core), the schema is meant to be changed [through the Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/schema-api.html).

However, if you stop Solr first, you can safely make edits to the managed-schema file, even if it tells you that you shouldn't hand edit it. Just make sure that nothing is running and relying on the state read from the file earlier - otherwise it'll be overwritten as the current state of the schema is written to the file.

If you want to use the classic schema.xml file, you can change your configuration to use the [ClassicIndexSchemaFactory instead](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-factory-definition-in-solrconfig.html) of the ManagedSchemaFactory.

You can change this definition in `solrconfig.xml` by adding

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory" />
```

Comment: You may need to mention where to change the "ClassicIndexSchemaFactory instead of the ManagedSchemaFactory." crayden will add another question for the same.